# ant replace tokens how to ignore new lines?

Tags: ant

I am copying a file while doing search and replace tokens in ant using replaceregex  tag
tokens exist in a separate text file  specified in the propertiesfile

```
token1=SDF234\n1sdfad
token2=FooBarBaz\nBar
```

the config.ini file has replacement values as : ${token1}

Some tokens have \n in them and the replaceregex adds a new line
I tried to add : byline="true" without success
I also added flags="m" to the replaceregex tag, it didn't work

sample token:

```
QWpVsL2Ti\njWhT\n
```

the code replaces it like:

```
 QWpVsL2Ti
 jWhT
```

the desired replacement should be in the same line ignoring the \n

ant task:

```
        <copy file="../../config.ini" tofile="./Package/config.ini">
                <filterchain>
                <replaceregex pattern="\$\{" replace="{" byline="true"/>
                    <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens">
                            <param type="propertiesfile" value="properties_${build_target}.ini"/>
                            <param type="tokenchar" name="begintoken" value="{"/>
                            <param type="tokenchar" name="endtoken" value="}"/>
                    </filterreader>
                </filterchain>
            </copy>
```

Comment: as a workaround i replaced all tokens from \n to \\n but this is not a good solution

Comment: I just tried it without the nested `<filterreader>` block and it worked fine.

Comment: but filterreader is what is doing the token replace

Comment: Yeah about that... why are you parsing Ant-style property references instead of just using the properties themselves? If you post the contents of one of your properties_${build_target}.ini files, i could probably come up with a better approach for you.